# jQuery prepend to all hyperlink elements that link to PDF files

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, prepend

I would like to prepend "Download a PDF of " to any hyperlinks, linking to PDF files.
Currently I'm able to prepend that exact text, but it prepends it to the hyperlink text. I would like it to reside outside of the hyperlink element, like so: Download a PDF of [hyperlink with text]

This is the code I'm using now:

```
jQuery('a[href$=.pdf]').prepend('Download a PDF of ');
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried before?

```
jQuery('a[href$=.pdf]').before('Download a PDF of ');
```

Comment: +1 great answer. It works: http://jsbin.com/akiba3 I confess, I took @BalusC's SSCCE and changed the one line out to use your solution to run my test.

Comment: Sweet! I <3 jQuery. It makes my life so much easier. =D

Comment: +1 I too had typed up Balus' answer, but discarded it when seeing this one :) Nice work, @AlteredConcept.

Answer (score 5):

The other selectors that have been provided in answers are wrong, as of today anyway. jQuery will complain:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href$=.pdf]

The right way to select the anchor is:

```
jQuery('a[href$=".pdf"]');
```

Note the quotes around .pdf

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it up in an inline element (e.g. `<span>`) and [insert it before](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) the desired elements. Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2172666</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('<span>Download a PDF of </span>').insertBefore('a[href$=.pdf]');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="foo.pdf">foo.pdf</a></p>
        <p><a href="foo.exe">foo.exe</a></p>
        <p><a href="bar.pdf">bar.pdf</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**: ah, as answered before, the [jQuery.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) works exactly the way you want, so I would go for it instead.

Comment: The `span` isn't needed, but it is needed using it the way you show here (with `$()` and `insertBefore`)  but +1 for updating your answer and providing a working example.

Comment: Yes exactly. I just wasn't fully aware about the existence and benefit of `before()`. Now I do :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will do what you're looking for:

```
<a href="foo.pdf">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.pdf">Bar</a>
<span id='foo'>Download a pdf of </span>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#foo').insertBefore('a[href$=.pdf]');
</script>
```